# xml DataTable export and change first line? C#

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, export, xmlwriter

How can I change the root element name from `<DocumentElement>` to `<table name = "UnknownTable">` when saving a `DataTable` to XML?

This is my code to create the xml file from the database:

```
peter = new MySqlCommand(cmd.CommandText, con);
                con.Open();
                dt = new DataTable("row");
                sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(peter);
                sda.Fill(dt);
                saveFileDialog1.Title = "Ticket speichern";
                saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML-File | *.xml";
                if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    settings.Indent = true;
                    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(saveFileDialog1.FileName, settings))
                    {
                        dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
                        xmlWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
```

this is the [created document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17cS9.png):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to write the `DataTable` to a temporary [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then rename the root element and add the necessary attribute(s).  The following extension method does the job:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static void WriteXml(this DataTable dt, XmlWriter writer, XName rootName, IEnumerable<XAttribute> rootAttributes = null)
    {
        if (dt == null || writer == null || rootName == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        var doc = new XDocument();
        using (var docWriter = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(docWriter);
        }
        if (doc.Root != null)
        {
            doc.Root.Name = rootName;
            if (rootAttributes != null)
                doc.Root.Add(rootAttributes);
        }
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
                dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter, "table", new[] { new XAttribute("name", "UnknownTable") });
```